# Как правильно настроить пагинацию Джанго?

Tags: python, django

views

```
def cat_detail(request, category_id):
    category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
     products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
    paginator = Paginator(products, 3) 
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request, 'product/cat_detail.html',
         {'category': category, 'products': products, 'page_obj': page_obj})
```

html

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

paginator = Paginator(products, 3) Эта строка во views не работаtn, отображаются все продукты, а не 3

Comment: извиняюсь, все продукты, а не страницы - опечатка

Comment: Тогда логично, что покажите код вывода продуктов — видимо, вы в нём вообще никак не используете page_obj

Comment: точно))спасибо, глупая ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не надо в контекст добавлять `product` ! В `page_obj` есть все необходимые аргументы -> `object_list` список записей текущей страницы

Comment: Спасибо, помогло